# Update object in hook

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm using a hook after the user unhide a record. In this hook i want to update a object.

```
class ProcessCmdmap {
    function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$reference) {
        if ($table == 'tx_oaevents_domain_model_events' && $status == 'update' && $fieldArray['hidden'] == 0) {

               // Get objectmanager
                $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

                // Get repo
                $repository = $objectManager->get('Mab\\Oaevents\\Domain\\Repository\\EventsRepository');

                // Get config manager
                $configurationManager = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\ConfigurationManagerInterface');

                // Get settings and storage pid
                $settings = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);
                $storagePid = $settings['plugin.']['tx_oaevents.']['persistence.']['storagePid'];

                // Build default query settings
                $querySettings = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
                $querySettings->setStoragePageIds(array($storagePid));

                $repository->setDefaultQuerySettings($querySettings);

                $object = $repository->findByUid($id);

                // modify object
                // Update / Persist object


        }
    }
}
```

But i can't retrieve a object with "findByUid()" or "findAll()". Do i use the objectmanager in wrong scope? Or how can retrieve and update into hooks my object?

Can someone give me a hint?

**Update**:

Now i give up :( and not use the objectmanager and repository, i use the functions from  `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']`

Answer (score 0):

I definitely recommend to follow your solution by using `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']` at this point. Extbase just brings in a lot of overhead here.

Without Extbase you also need less code here.

Anyway:
Most likely the generated queries by Extbase are broken. Log your queries and check the generated one. Try it out and modify it, until it works. Check the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can try without using "setStoragePageIds".
If you are looking record by uid it is useless.

My working code for processDatamap:

```
/** @var $objectManager \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager */
$objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

/** @var $orderRepository \Vendor\ExtensionName\Domain\Repository\OrderRepository */
$orderRepository = $objectManager->get('Vendor\\ExtensionName\\Domain\\Repository\\OrderRepository');
$order = $orderRepository->findByUid($id);
```

It is true that the use of $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB'] is easier.